# Trouble with DMARC and Google Apps / GSuite

Tags: google-workspace, dmarc

I've had the following DMARC policy setup for over a year, but in the last two weeks I'm suddenly unable to send emails to many people. Yet I haven't changed this record. I am experienced with DNS, server administration and programming yet I cannot find any explanation for this issue.

**What are the solutions to this problem?**

**Existing DMARC Record**

`v=DMARC1; p=reject; pct=100; rua=mailto:re+something@dmarc.postmarkapp.com; ruf=mailto:me@mydomain.com; sp=none; aspf=r; fo=1;`

**Error I get when emailing various emails (@gmail.com and custom domains).**

https://gist.github.com/s3w47m88/115688a7ecd5a8c762bd3f98932756b2

**Headers for Successful Email**

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Wed, 10 Apr 2019 15:26:48 -0700
References: <BN7PR06MB4116507B5F036C4D175E082CC82E0@BN7PR06MB4116.namprd06.prod.outlook.com> <CAN9OK_OfgXw_mW2+M-=TkHLupnOdBo=VyE=wQOALykc8=EzjXA@mail.gmail.com> <BN7PR06MB411654D8A0AA5D44F92E1D1EC82E0@BN7PR06MB4116.namprd06.prod.outlook.com> <CAN9OK_PMipqHaLK9W-PAn0_dhsD876TpETq85CeVC5NBQpCPig@mail.gmail.com> <BN7PR06MB4116592A4D4E6B4EBE299EF5C82E0@BN7PR06MB4116.namprd06.prod.outlook.com>
In-Reply-To: <BN7PR06MB4116592A4D4E6B4EBE299EF5C82E0@BN7PR06MB4116.namprd06.prod.outlook.com>
Bcc: 5729491@bcc.hubspot.com
Message-ID: <CAN9OK_O-WEFqJysAr8S51LrBa1_fopy1UoFVSxq5JWNeeMuZCQ@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Re: Your free trial
From: Me <me@mydomain.com>
To: John Doe <someone@asite.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="000000000000d3115405863490ac"

--000000000000d3115405863490ac
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Comment: Your `return-path` seems to be `secureserver.net`, while your signing DKIM with the selector `google` for your domain. Can you shed some light on how you are routing your emails? If somehow you route your emails via GoDaddy / SecureServer and that updates the bounce address (on which SPF is checked) and breaks your DKIM signing, than that would explain why DMARC fails.
It would be great if you could add the headers for a successfully received email that was sent via the same route. The Authentication-Results header should point out what is happening. Also, Did you check PostmarkApp (rua)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. GoDaddy isn't involved at all on our side. So I don't know how it's possible that's appearing in the return path. I'll update this momentarily with a successful header.

Comment: SecureServer.net could indicate a forward set up at the initial recipient. Forwards sometime break authentication, by changing the Return-Path (for bounces). That will remove the alignment with the original sender's email domain.
Unfortunately your headers example doesn't show the authentication-results. Did you take this excerpt from Gmail? If so, I'm looking for the info placed above the MIME-version. Specifically: Return-Path, Authentication Results, Received-SPF, DKIM-Signature and ARC- headers, if any.